# How to split an already aggregated PCollection into windows?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that processes timeseries data for different users in 10-minute sliding windows that I would like to be able to run with two separate input methods. The first, which I have working, does something like

```py
pipeline
   | ReadFromPubSub(...)
   | WindowInto(SlidingWindows(...))
   | WithKeys(lambda message: message.user_id)
   | GroupByKey()
   | TransformIntoNumpyArray()
   | ActuallyInterestingWork()
```

But for the second, I have all of the data in a local folder with one file per user, each as a serialized numpy array already. I know I could read each file and emit every point individually to be able to use the same `WindowInto(SlidingWindows(...))` logic, but it seems silly and inefficient to emit each point only to later join them back into the numpy arrays I already had. It feels like there should be a way to use `Partition` (or something else I'm unaware of) here to avoid that, while still ensuring later stages of the pipeline can reference `DoFn.WindowParam`. I don't mind manually writing the code to partition the data into windows, I'm just unsure how to do so in such a way as to preserve the window context.

In code:

```py
pipeline
    | Create(os.listdir(input_folder))
    | DeserializeData()
    # ??? The data should already be grouped by user just by the nature
    # of how we structured Create, but how can we split this into windows?
    | ActuallyInterestingWork()
```

Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Comment: Is the output of the first pipeline the input to the second, or are they unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly, each output from the first pipeline will contain an array of all the elements for a particular user *for a particular window* already. So the data is already partitioned. If that is the input to the second pipeline, then you can simply read each file and process the contents as desired.

On the other hand, if your second pipeline is unrelated and has all the data for a user in a single array but they are not grouped into windows, then you will need to do some work. It depends on the size of the data. Since it is a single numpy array, I will assume it is manageable in memory. In this case, the most efficient thing would be to Do It Yourself: write a DoFn that uses numpy bulk operations to implement the assignment of individual data points to sliding windows and then group those. Of course, you'll have some data blowup. If this exceeds what you can process on a single machine, then you'll want go ahead and use Beam's primitives.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The second pipeline is unrelated, other than that I want to share code for `ActuallyInterestingWork()`, and the format of the data is as you say. The DIY DoFn sounds like what I'm going for, I'm just unclear how to do that in a way where later DoFns that use `window=DoFn.WindowParam` can get the proper window value from the context. Or do you mean do something like completely split the array up into `beam.transforms.window.TimestampedValues` and then use the built-in `WindowInto`? I think it's the actual window assignment that I don't understand.

Comment: Aha! Note that `WindowInto` is *just barely* a primitive, and the provided `WindowFn` are just the most common (fixed, sliding, sessions) but not built in or executed specially. They are actually pretty easy to write. Your approach of emitting the split array will be necessary. You can either do it as you said, or you can embed the window in the output and write your own WindowFn to pull it out and assign it.